# how can i move my snake head with my arrow keys

Tags: python

***what did I do wrong because I cant move the snakehead with my wasd key the error that I keep on getting is turtle.terminator, It also say the problem is at the wn update place can u please tell me the solution this move the sane head i tried every thing this always come up raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator***

```
import turtle
import time
import random

delay = 0.1
# Set up the screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake")
wn.bgcolor("blue")
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Snake head
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.shape("square")
head.color("red")
head.penup()
head.goto(0, 0)
head.direction = "stop"

# snake food
food = turtle.Turtle()
food.speed(0)
food.shape("circle")
food.color("green")
food.penup()
food.goto(0, 100)

segments = []


# function
def go_up():
head.direction = "up"


def go_down():
head.direction = "down"


def go_left():
head.direction = "left"


def go_right():
head.direction = "right"


def move():
if head.direction == "up":
    y = head.ycor()
    head.sety(y + 20)

if head.direction == "down":
    y = head.ycor()
    head.sety(y - 20)

if head.direction == "left":
    x = head.xcor()
    head.setx(x - 20)

if head.direction == "right":
    x = head.xcor()
    head.setx(x + 20)


# key board bindings
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(go_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(go_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(go_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(go_right, "d")

# Main game loop
while True:
wn.update()

if head.distance(food) < 20:
    # move the food to random spot
    x = random.randint(-290, 290)
    y = random.randint(-290, 290)
    food.goto(x, y)

    # add a segment
    new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
    new_segment.speed(0)
    new_segment.shape("square")
    new_segment.color("grey")
    new_segment.penup()
    segments.append(new_segment)

# move the end segments frist in revrves order
for index in range(len(segments) - 1, 0, -1):
    x = segments[index - 1].xcor()
    y = segments[index - 1].ycor()
    segments[index].goto(x, y)

# segment 0 to where the is
if len(segments) > 0:
    x = head.xcor()
    y = head.ycor()
    segments[0].goto(x, y)
move()

time.sleep(delay)
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for moving. You have to call `move()` method after go_up etc.

```
import turtle
import time
import random

delay = 0.1
# Set up the screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake")
wn.bgcolor("blue")
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Snake head
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.shape("square")
head.color("red")
head.penup()
head.goto(0, 0)
head.direction = "stop"

# snake food
food = turtle.Turtle()
food.speed(0)
food.shape("circle")
food.color("green")
food.penup()
food.goto(0, 100)

segments = []


# function
def go_up():
    head.direction = "up"
    move()

def go_down():
    head.direction = "down"
    move()

def go_left():
    head.direction = "left"
    move()

def go_right():
    head.direction = "right"
    move()

def move():
    print("Move")
    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y + 20)

    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y - 20)

    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x - 20)

    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x + 20)


# key board bindings# key board bindings
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(go_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(go_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(go_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(go_right, "d")

# Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

    if head.distance(food) < 20:
        # move the food to random spot
        x = random.randint(-290, 290)
        y = random.randint(-290, 290)
        food.goto(x, y)

        # add a segment
        new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
        new_segment.speed(0)
        new_segment.shape("square")
        new_segment.color("grey")
        new_segment.penup()
        segments.append(new_segment)

    # move the end segments frist in revrves order
    for index in range(len(segments) - 1, 0, -1):
        x = segments[index - 1].xcor()
        y = segments[index - 1].ycor()
        segments[index].goto(x, y)

    # segment 0 to where the is
    if len(segments) > 0:
        x = head.xcor()
        y = head.ycor()
        segments[0].goto(x, y)


time.sleep(delay)
wn.mainloop()
```